# Accessing resources.xml/appContext.xml defined beans in a grails unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a grails application that uses a appContext.xml to define beans. It all works when I run the application. But when I try to run unit tests with the @ContextConfiguration all the auto wired beans are null.

How can I unit test loading beans via @autowired .

Thanks 
Chris G

Answer (score 2):

There's not much happening under the hood in unit tests - they're very lightweight. There's a small ApplicationContext but it only has a few mocked beans, but nothing from plugins, your application, etc. Use integration tests to have a proper Spring environment.

Answer (score 0):

One of sample way of doing assuming your appContext file is inside **grailsApp/Conf/Spring** folder

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ["classpath:spring/appContext.xml.xml" ])
class SampleTest  {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    UserDao userDao;
}
```